# Control style Inherited the default style using BasedOn,but at runtime throw exception:Cannot find resource named xxx

Tags: wpf

I customized a control SCExpander,and have a defalut style like this

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type sc:SCExpander}">
</Style>
```

Now I want to define another style based on what I did before,like this

```
<Style
        x:Key="NormalSCExpander"
        BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type sc:SCExpander}}"
        TargetType="{x:Type sc:SCExpander}">
</Style>
```

At runtime throw  exception:Cannot find resource named sc:SCExpander

Why is there a mistake? Can someone help me

Comment: Where do you define the styles, where are they placed?